# How to load in data from database to listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, sqlconnection

My program can load in the listbox headers, but not the actually data from the whole table.

(how I am connecting to the database):

```
const string connectionString = "Data Source=test;Initial Catalog=dbi391731;User ID=test;Password=test";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

I'm using a class to load in the data:

```
public List<ScoreMdw> GetScoreMdwList()
        {
            List<ScoreMdw> scoremdwList = new List<ScoreMdw>();
            conn.Open();
            string query = ("Select employeeid, questionid, score from contentment");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            try
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        ScoreMdw sm = new ScoreMdw((int)dr["employeeid"], (int)dr["questionid"], (char)dr["score"]);
                        scoremdwList.Add(sm);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Exception error = new Exception("error", ex);
                throw error;
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            return scoremdwList;
        }
```

In the while loop I'm using an other class:

```
class ScoreMdw
    {
        private int employeeid;
        private int questionid;
        private char score;

        public ScoreMdw(int nr, int id, char s)
        {
            this.employeeid= nr;
            this.questionid= id;
            this.score = s;
        }

        public int EmployeeId
        {
            get { return employeeid; }
        }

        public int QuestionId
        {
            get { return questionid; }
        }

        public char Score
        {
            get { return score; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string s = string.Format("{0} \t{1} \t{2}", this.employeeid, this.questionid, this.score);
            return s;
        }
    }
```

In my main window I'm doing this:

```
 private void btnLoadScores_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            scoremdwList = new List<ScoreMdw>();

            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                List<string> headers = so.GetContentmentHeaders();

                foreach (string header in headers)
                    txtHeader.Text += header + "\t";

                scoremdwList = so.GetScoreMdwList();
                lbScores.ItemsSource = scoremdwList;
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

I get the error that I made in the class ("error"). I don't know what I'm doing wrong? Maybe something with the connection? Am I opening and closing it the wrong way?

Comment: What kind of error message found in the exception thrown? Probably the `dr` column value casting was throwing exception.

Comment: I got the error message that I've made in the class (catch Exception), and that is "error".

Answer (score 0):

May i ask you, to show us the ex.Message? So we know what the possible error could be.

```
try
{
   using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
       while(dr.read())
       {
          ScoreMdw sm = new ScoreMdw((int)dr["employeeid"], (int)dr["questionid"], (char)dr["score"]);
          scoremdwList.Add(sm);
       }
   }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message); // <= here you will get you errormessage that is important to fix your error.
   Exception error = new Exception("error", ex);
   throw error;
}
```

Comment: The message I get is "error" which I made here:
catch (Exception ex)
           {
                Exception error = new Exception("error", ex);
                throw error;
            }

Comment: catch (Exception ex)
{
    Exception error = new Exception("error", ex);
    throw error;
} in this section you got your ex (Exception) this ex has a Property called "Message". In thsis Message you can see your error message. So you need to look at this place. I hope you know and understood what i try to explain to you.

Comment: Yes, the message is error, just what I have there in the bracket.